# How to fix error HTTP Status 500 Target Unreachable, identifier '...' resolved to null" in java spring mvc running Application?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

This application is running fine in another system but it shows some error like

> HTTP Status 500 - //F:/GulfNet_Dev_Env/apexjava/apex-webapp/src/main/webapp/login.xhtml @53,68 value="#{userController.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'userController' resolved to null"

I attach code regarding my question:

````
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:event listener="#{userController.login}" type="preRenderView" />
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    </f:facet>
    <title>Apex</title>
    <ui:insert name="head" />
</h:head>

<h:body styleClass="loginbodyblue">
    <ui:fragment
        rendered="#{userBean.mmsuser != null and userBean.mmsuser.username != null}">
        <script>
            window.location.href = "views/home.xhtml";
        </script>
    </ui:fragment>
    <h:form>
        <p:growl />
        <div class="Wid90 DispBlock MarAuto MarTopPerc5 TexAlCenter">
            <div class="Wid33 MarAuto WidAutoOnMobile">
                <h:graphicImage name="images/apex-logo.png" />
                <div class="EmptyBox30"></div>
                <div class="Card ShadowEffect">
                    <div class="EmptyBox20"></div>
                    <div class="Wid100 OvHidden BigTopic Fs30">
                        <i class="icon-users Fs40"></i> Login
                    </div>
                    <div class="EmptyBox20"></div>

                    <ui:fragment
                        rendered="#{userBean.mmsuser == null or userBean.mmsuser.username == null}">
                        <div class="Wid100">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Userid" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <p:inputText placeholder="Userid" required="true"
                                    style="border-bottom: solid 1px #c1c2c3;"
                                    requiredMessage="Username is required"
                                    value="#{userBean.username}" styleClass="Wid80 Fs18 ">
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="companyit user_Name"
                                        listener="#{userController.displayCompany}" />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Username" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:inputText readonly="true" placeholder="Username"
                                    style="border-bottom: solid 1px #c1c2c3;" id="user_Name"
                                    value="#{userBean.uName}" styleClass="Wid80 Fs18 ">

                                </p:inputText>
                            </div>



                        </div>
                        <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>
                        <div class="Wid100">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:inputText type="password" required="true"
                                    style="border-bottom: solid 1px #c1c2c3;"
                                    requiredMessage="Password is required"
                                    value="#{userBean.password}" placeholder="Password"
                                    styleClass="Wid80 Fs18 " />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Wid100" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Company" style="padding-right: 13px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="companyit" styleClass="Wid70 Fs18 "
                                    style="    width: 82%;" filter="true"
                                    filterMatchMode="startsWith" value="#{userBean.defaultco}">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.defaultcos}" var="company"
                                        itemLabel="#{company.descr}" itemValue="#{company.descr}" />

                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </ui:fragment>


                    <div class="EmptyBox30"></div>
                    <!-- <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="accept" itemLabel="I Accept Terms And Policies"/>
                    <div class="EmptyBox30"></div> -->
                    <!--  <div class="Wid100"><p:button value="Sign In" icon="fa fa-sign-in" styleClass="Wid60 Fs18 White RaisedButton" href="dashboard.xhtml"/></div> -->
                    <div class="EmptyBox5"></div>
                    <!-- <div class="Wid100"><p:button value="Forgot Password ?" icon="fa fa-lock" styleClass="RedButton Wid60 Fs18 White RaisedButton"/></div> -->
                    <!-- <div class="EmptyBox20"></div> -->
                    <div class="Separator"></div>
                    <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>
                    <div class="Wid100">
                        <ui:fragment
                            rendered="#{userBean.mmsuser == null or userBean.mmsuser.username == null}">
                            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Sign In"
                                icon="fa fa-sign-in" styleClass="Wid60 Fs18 White RaisedButton"
                                action="#{userController.doLogin}" />
                        </ui:fragment>


                    </div>
                    <div class="EmptyBox20"></div>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="Wid100 TexAlCenter MarTop20 Fs14 FontRobotoRegular WhiteBlue">
                    <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> Apex ERP | All rights reserved.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/core-layout.css" library="rio-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/animate.css" library="rio-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/rio-font.css" library="rio-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/ripple-effect.css" library="rio-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/font-awesome.css" library="rio-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/rio-layout.css" library="rio-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/apex-layout-theme.css"
        library="apex-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.min.css" library="bootstrap" />
</h:body>

</html> ```
````

Comment: Edited your formatting to be little bit clearer.

Comment: "userController" bean couldn't be resolved. check if it is defined in your configuration properly.

Comment: @majid how can I check?